# Is there a Windows exe that does nothing?

Tags: windows

Is there a "noop"-esque exe somewhere as part of the Windows installation? I'm preparing some batch jobs and scheduled tasks, and for a couple reasons I'd like to reference an executable that does nothing -- i.e. launches with no visible window, and quits immediately.

Does such an executable exist in the usual Windows installation anywhere? or how can I come close? I do not want to have to depend on anything not already included in Windows.

Comment: From observation: `svchost.exe` doesn't open anything.

Comment: @todda.speot.is you should include that as a full answer.

Comment: Did it have to be an external (executable) file? If not, then the `rem` command could have worked (and depending on where in the batch-file it is being used, possibly even the `::` variant).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You may use `rundll32`:

- No console window
- No side effects
- Just 44 KB
- No arguments required
- Works on every recent Windows version (XP, Vista, 7), and probably on every NT-based system.

Comment: So why is it there?

Comment: @Nathan With the appropriate arguments, it can call a function inside of a DLL

Comment: Right. For example, imagine a simple `print.exe` program that simply prints out the parameters it is passed. Without any arguments it would *do nothing*, but giving it arguments *does something*: `> print foobar`.

Comment: @Andrea then it doesn't do nothing unless given no arguments. Though that is nothingy enough as per his requirements.

Comment: i think rundll32.exe is beaten by hh.exe (See answer somebody posted in april).  if taking size into account,   hh.exe is less characters in length of filename. it resides in c:\windows which is even smaller path than c:\windows\system32, and is smaller in size at 16KB. Though both are probably beaten by synetech's assembly language post.

Comment: Except it is probably not really a no-op.

Answer (score 47):

> Is there a "noop"-esque exe somewhere as part of the Windows installation?

Meaning specifically a program that is meant to do nothing and nothing else? Yes and no. No in that Windows does not include one by default, but it does include the ability to make one yourself.

## Option 1

Run **notepad.exe**, type the following lines, and save it as `C:\ret.scr` (don’t forget the blank line):

```
a
ret

rcx
1
n ret.com
w
q
```

Compile it with **debug.exe** at the command-prompt (**cmd.exe**) with following command:

```
C:\> debug < ret.scr
```

You now have a program, `ret.com` (in C:\) that can be used in batch files which does absolutely nothing whatsoever (well, other than quit, if that counts).

**Note**: `debug` is not included on 64-bit systems.

## Option 2

In Vista and up, the .NET framework is included by default, so you could also make a native, Windows do-nothing `.exe` with C# ([64-bit compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zekwfyz4.aspx)):

Run **notepad.exe** and type the following lines, saving it as `C:\ret.cs`:

```
class ret
{
   static void Main() {
   }
}
```

Compile it with **csc.exe** at the command-prompt (**cmd.exe**) with the following command:

```
C:\> csc ret.cs /target:winexe
```

You now have another program, `ret.exe` (in C:\) that can be used in batch files which does nothing but return. The target option makes it a GUI app so it does not even open a terminal window.

Comment: Damn Brilliant.. everybody should upvote you for that one.. I always wanted to learn assembly language.. I never used debug and thought it died with DOS. So glad I stumbled on your answer here. maybe fodder for a future hobby!

Comment: For me, `csc.exe` was not on my path, but it was located at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe`

Comment: what about an EXE which is compiled from a C program which just has a main method, like your csc.exe Is that doing much much more than the program you wrote in debug?  for example, is there much much more assembly language there with that program?

Comment: @barlop, generally yes. While an empty `main` function seems like it would, or at least *should* be nothing more than a `ret`, if you open such a program in a disassembler (or even a hex-editor), you will see that it is much, much more than that. It will usually set up all kinds of segments (code, data, etc.), prepare stacks and heaps, not to mention import all kinds of functions and strings and such even if it never actually uses them.

Comment: I needed this one to replace some old external support software for an installation kit, reducing the package size, where that software is not needed anymore, like DirectX and VCruntimes. Also, if you don't have or want to install any compiler, use online compilers from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm, after compilation, download the project and it'll have the exe inside the archive.

Comment: On my Windows 8.1 x64 system I had the same issue that @AlcubierreDrive did above (I had to go and find the .NET Framework path). On my system there were a number of versions (I chose the last) each on a different path: 
* C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe
* C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe
* C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
* C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\csc.exe
* C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\csc.exe
* C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe

Answer (score 11):

There aren't any programs included with Windows (that I know of) which immediately exit when executed (at least on purpose.)

In Windows Vista and newer, however, there is the [timeout.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) utility. `Timeout.exe` will wait a specified number of seconds and then exit. For example:

```
C:\>timeout /t 0 > nul:
```

Setting `timeout.exe` to wait for 0 seconds is about as close as a you'll get to an EXE that immediately exits.

Comment: To do what the Op wants, use timeout like this "timeout /t 0 > nul:" - which will run the timeout command without any output and will quit immediately.

Comment: @misterjaytee good idea.

Comment: @Tom: A *console window*. It won't open a command prompt unless you run `cmd.exe` specifically.

Comment: @grawity: The Task Scheduler needs a command processor for the command to run, hence the console window will briefly show.

Comment: @TomWijsman Try as I might, I can't get any new window to open up.

Answer (score 6):

Without parameters "C:\Windows\hh.exe" (Microsoft® HTML Help Executable) does nothing and it is included in any Windows-Version I guess.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried `rndll32.exe` and `hh.exe` but both of then didn't alter the %ERRORLEVEL%. It is an environment variable that says if the last executable was successful. Works like the unix return code.

My noop command below will set the %ERRORLEVEL% to zero is:

```
cd %CD%
```

Just changing the working directory to the current one.

Comment: (1) There's a difference between `nop` and `ret`. (2) `cd` is a console command, so it will flash a console window if you run it from outside a console, so it's not exactly no-op.

Answer (score 2):

`wscript` with no arguments runs no script at all, and is a "GUI" executable (does not open a console).

Comment: When I run wscript with no arguments I get a "Windows Script Host Settings" that appears. Windows 7 64-bit. Running `wscript /b` seems to work though.

Answer (score 0):

the command `echo off` does nothing within a batch (.BAT) file. Although it is not an executable it is an windows internal command.

Comment: Actually it *does* do something, it turns echoing off. That might seem like nothing if you have it set to off, but if you *want* echoing, then it certainly does do something.

Comment: and like rem, it's not a windows exe

Answer (score 0):

Compile a simple "Hello World" C++ program to create a simple exe which would exit immediately.
Save following code in a text file with some name like a.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{ std::cout<<"Hello World";
return 0;
}
```

Then, compile it with LATEST C++ compiler like MinGW for Windows 7.
In case of MinGW, execute following command in PowerShell or Command Prompt: `g++ path\a.cpp` (Assuming that you have set environmental PATH variable of g++ binary location or you are in g++ binary directory i.e. c:\mingw\bin by default). After command execution, you will get a.exe which will display Hello World and exit. Verify by double-click... cmd window will appear and disappear immediately. Command line access will display Hello World and return you to CLI prompt.
Then, you can move this a.exe in system32 or anywhere deep inside Windows. You can even roll it out in installation disk of Windows.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that a C++ compiler is not included with Windows.

Comment: Printing "Hello World" is hardly doing nothing.

Comment: @Synetech Compilation is required only one time as long as CPU architecture is same..

Comment: @KeithThompson I don't think it would interference with BAT algorithm, but if it really matters, replace Hello World with ASCII null character..

Comment: *> Compilation is required only one time as long as CPU architecture is same* Well obviously, but the OP asked if there is a no-op program that *comes with Windows*. If you are going to start throwing in ideas that require third-party programs, then you may as well forgo this and just link to [an already-made one](http://www.google.com/search?q=exe+does+nothing&safe=off). (For the record, a long time ago, I went the compile-a-do-nothing-exe route myself. It’s 518 bytes and DOS compatible. I wonder what the heck I compiled it with.) `:-)`

Comment: *> I don't think it would interference with BAT algorithm, but if it really matters, replace Hello World with ASCII null character* Or just remove the print command altogether.

Comment: @Synetech :) yup.. removing print command would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a no-op in C like so

```c
void main() {

}
```

and compile it into an .exe file. For example, if you have Visual Studio installed, you can open notepad, paste that snippet, save it as noop.c and in the command prompt use `cl noop.c` and it will output a `noop.exe` file in the same folder.

You may or may not have to browse to the `Microsoft Visual Studio X.0` folder in `Program Files` first and run `vcvarsall.bat` from the command prompt.

Comment: You missed the part of the question that said "part of a Windows installation". Also, the semicolon is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

`doskey.exe` does nothing and it is in the path by default: it is included on System32 on virtually all Windows systems.