# Is there an exe that does nothing except have an open window?

Tags: windows, .net-framework

I'm looking for  an executable file that I can run, leave open however long I would like, then close at will. Does such a program exist? I looked at the great answers provided on this question: [Is there a Windows exe that does nothing?](https://superuser.com/questions/381103/is-there-a-windows-exe-that-does-nothing). The issue is that  all of those solutions literally do nothing (as the user requested), where as I want my exe to stay running with a window or popup box until closed.

If this does not already exist, is there a simple .NET script that could do this which I could compile to an executable?

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)?

Comment: No, this is a very specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to make a program to do this, it is *super* easy.  Just download and install [Visual Studio Express](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/express/).  Create a Windows Form application and click build.  Thats it.

Alternatively, you can write a VBScript script with the following code in Notepad or the editor of your choice:

```
x=msgbox("Nothing" ,0, "Nothing")
```

And save it as `yourscript.vbs`.  Double clicking the file will launch the script.

Technically, its not an executable.  You could use a VBSript compiler like [VBSEdit](https://www.vbsedit.com/) to "compile" it to an executable.  However, its not really compiling the code into an executable program.  It is actually embedding and running the script host and then running the script.

Comment: Yeah I considered doing this however it needs to be an exe, I'll look into a compiler

Answer (score -1):

You can use a temporary batch file for doing this:

```
@echo off
:: If you want the batch file Ctrl C resistant, than add /NoBreak switch at next line before >nul
timeout /t %1 >nul 
exit /b 0
```

Save it as wait.bat and Now you can call it like:

```
start wait.bat number_of_seconds
```

Comment: Hi Wasif, unfortunetly it needs to be an exe file. I'm also a batch expert and have been working with a team looking at the most popular batch compilers. One of them certainly has malware in it so we're reviewing all of them. Basically, because of this, I would like to make a native exe not an embedded exe.

Answer (score -1):

In visual studio open a c++ file and type the following:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
   MessageBox(NULL, L"Enter your text here", L"Here enter your title", MB_OK);
}
```

And then export it as an exe file.

If you wanna open a blank window it requires more code so ask if you still need it. Also, i'm a beginner so my piece of code may not be the perfect solution. It can probably be made just with a compiler without the need of downloading the whole Visual Studio but that's what i'm currently using.