# Context switching out of Remote Desktop via keyboard command

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, autohotkey

##### Problem:

I need to swap between the RDP context and the windows host context so that key commands like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd> work as intended in their given environments.

---

##### Environment:

I'm running Windows 10 on both the host and remote, and using RDP to connect. I'm using ICUE as my primary keyboard macro software on the host end, though I'm not averse to directing things at an autohotkey script or a custom c# executable.

---

##### Previous Research:

1. I can get this to work successfully by making ICUE open my web browser in the host context (and switch to it) and that's fairly simple to do with a macro key. The issue then is that web browsers are generally fairly slow to instantiate, and require closing.
2. I created a null executable as recommended in [this question](https://superuser.com/a/393508/968848) but I get the feeling that since it doesn't have an attached window, it closes without a focus switch.
3. I can't simply do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> because RDP gobbles the command, and I need to be able to use <kbd>Win</kbd> in both RDP and host. I know I can use <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> to swap but I don't like that solution because it restricts my access to the RDP <kbd>Win</kbd> key and my <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key is basically a handspan away from my page keys, which is obviously uncomfortable to do.
4. Given the plethora of monitors in my normal setup, I have been using an autohotkey script bound to <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to set a window to be always on top, then clicking over to this window when I need to to switch back to host.

---

##### Question:

What might be a good option for creating such a context-switching key command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great post... I have had very similar needs in the past and have a few ways I've been able to do this (or similar enough to adapt to what you're trying to do)--I tend to leverage AutoHotkey but you can use whatever.

1. Run two background scripts or programs, one local, one remote, using the shared clipboard capability of RDP or similar remote-desktop software.  Trigger a hotkey of your choice on the remote side to set the clipboard to a unique string, and detect that string on the clipboard on the local side (since the clipboard will automatically get passed back to the local side where changes can be detected, for example in AutoHotkey using the `OnClipboard` command).  On the local side you can then execute whatever you want (restore the window if you like, or shell-execute another program). Finally, on the remote or local side, the original clipboard can be restored or wiped after action is taken. This has worked very well for me but the only downside--depending on your connection latency--is the transfer time of the clipboard on your link.  This method didn't always feel 'snappy' per se, but was perfectly functional.
2. Use a keyboard that leverages keyboard-specific driver/software. Logitech has this for most of their keyboards as well as other USB add-on keypads. On a Logitech keyboard for example, you can set Fn+[F1 through F12] to run another program, script, etc.  So for example you can assign Fn+F10 to run a program that will restore the RDP window, and this keypress will not get sent to the RDP session since the Logitech driver/software detects it and will run the program locally that it's assigned to run. A slight variation on this that can also be used if you don't want to change keyboards is to get a separate USB keypad--there are cheaper and more expensive versions, but anything that comes with a driver program where you can set it to run an external program or executable will work.
3. Finally, an option I have not implemented before, but which may be feasible, is using AutoHotkey HID code to use an additional keyboard or mouse you have laying around (so it has the same keys basically and you might have one handy, vs. having to buy something).  In this scenario, you detect HID-specific input from that device (vs. your regular keyboard/mouse), even though it would be sending the same keys/buttons, and then execute a program locally to restore the RDP window.

Comment: I love the idea of using the clipboard as a message passing medium, but since I'm not a domain admin on remote (and no sysadmin ever has considered autohotkey safe) it's a no-go there. Using keyboard software as an intermediary seems like my best bet and just confirms what I already knew: It'll work if I just put the effort in...

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this specific problem is as follows:

I have the following autohotkey executable script compiled on host:

```
WinActivate Program Manager
return
```

This sets the "focused" window to be my host desktop (*without* minimizing to desktop like <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> does). Then it closes the script.

I set this up as key-actuated executable in ICUE (though I don't doubt similar could be implemented in other vendor-specific keyboard software) such that when I press that particular macro key AND I'm in a key-gobbling app such as RDP or Hyper-V, it triggers the script.