# Prevent Chrome from opening online help URLs from other apps

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, redirection

As with many applications, pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> often brings up a help menu, sometimes using Google Chrome as a launchpad for help files that are hosted online. I often press <kbd>F1</kbd> by mistake when using 3dsMax, and it really disrupts my workflow when Chrome is launched over top of 3dsMax.

**Is there a way to prevent Google Chrome from opening these types of online help files?**

I'm not interested in creating an AHK script to remap <kbd>F1</kbd> because I need it for other apps.

Running Windows 10 Pro

Chrome Version 114.0.5735.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: You can remap in AHK only if Chrome is active. Very doubtful that you can disable it in Chrome directly. But I'm not sure if you mean you're pressing F1 in Chrome or if you open some links for documentation in other apps.

Comment: @Destroy666 thanks for the reply. Not pressing in Chrome, pressing F1 in 3dsMax.

Comment: In that case, you need to rebind/disable it in these specific apps. Nothing you can do with the URL opening mechanism itself, if it brings you to a website that uses HTTP protocol then Windows can't do anything. You could use 3rd party apps like https://alternativeto.net/software/browserselector/ perhaps, but you need to show some URL examples of the help documents for an accurate answer to be provided.

Comment: I read that there is no way to remap the F1 key in 3dsMax, so I guess there no way to do this.

Comment: You can always do it with AFK as I said, just for 3dsMax. But share the help link URL displayed in the browser and maybe the above solution will be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent it in 2 ways:

### Use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)

To prevent F1 hotkey in specific apps, you can use a short script. This should stop it in 3dsMax, for instance:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe 3dsmax.exe
F1::return
```

### Use a tool like [BrowseRouter](https://github.com/slater1/BrowseRouter)

1. Download the app, add it to `%PATH%` if needed.
2. Register it with `BrowseRouter --register`.
3. Edit the config `.ini` so that your executable:

```ini
; Register browsers, we add one fake one as "nothing"
; that executes rundll32 exe which doesn't do anything
; https://superuser.com/questions/381103/is-there-a-windows-exe-that-does-nothing
[browsers]
ff = C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
chrome = C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
nothing = rundll32
    
; Match window title here and redirect it to "nothing"
; * are wildcards
[sources]
*3ds Max* = nothing
```

This will work assuming it's opening just regular HTTP(S) websites.